# "Undefined" labels and buttons in the UI of SuiteCRM

Tags: cpanel, file-permissions, sugarcrm, message, suitecrm

A fresh installation, installed via an installer (Softaculous, to save time.)

Data seems to be correctly connected and all in the correct places. But most error messages only contain the word "undefined."

I have a feeling it's a permission problem, but the various solutions for it on forums are varied and only seem to work for a small section of people for each.

I'd rather not do a reinstall as all the old data from previous CRM is now imported.

This is running through a cPanel controlled server BTW, if that helps matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Suite or Sugar install is installed on a temporary I.P whilst using cPanel, at least in our version of cPanel, it hosts the files in a temporary test folder.

Suite (specifically SugarBean.php) tries to access the folders that would exist on permanent domains. So it calls files that are hosted elsewhere on the server.

Soon as the site was pointed to a real domain, it fixed itself, no extra steps necessary, as the files were hosted in the correct place.

Thanks to the hosting company, they explained that to me. I'm not sure if that's standard procedure to store the files differently for temporary i.p addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's permission issues. Please update write permission for the web server user and try to delete " **cache/jsLanguage/en_us.j**s " folder from your account.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if cPanel allows ChOwn command. Changed permission for the files though.

Comment: It really wasn't.

It turns out it's an old bug from Sugar which is still in Suite but is so rare that it's pointless for them to spend ages fixing it.

If a Suite or Sugar install is installed on a temporary I.P whilst using cPanel, it tries to access the folders that would exist on permanent domains. So it calls files that are hosted elsewhere on the server.

Soon as the site was pointed to a real domain, it fixed itself, no extra steps necessary.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using correct .htaccess

Go to `Admin > Repair` and do a `"Quick Repair & Rebuild"`. Execute any changes shown at the bottom of the page.

If that doesn't work, go to `Admin > Repair` and do `"Rebuild .htaccess file"` and afterwards, `Admin > Repair` and do a `"Quick Repair & Rebuild"` again.